# Loop always sets the last data to TextView in Android

Tags: android, json, server, retrofit, android-cardview

I get data from server side to my RecyclerView but the code always sets the last text to my TextView. I am so confused. Can you help me? Thanks. I am sharing my code below.

```
  private void bindDatas() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NewsService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    NewsService newsService = retrofit.create(NewsService.class);
    final Call<NewsCatalog> requestCatalog = newsService.newsCatalog();


    requestCatalog.enqueue(new Callback<NewsCatalog>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Response<NewsCatalog> response) {
            NewsCatalog catalog = response.body();
            SubNodes subNodes = new SubNodes();
            mainNodes = new MainNodes();


            for (int i = 0; i < catalog.nodes.size(); i++) {
                mainNodes = catalog.nodes.get(i);
                Log.i(TAG, "" + mainNodes.node.body);

                subNodes.setBody(mainNodes.node.body);

                subNodesList.add(subNodes);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your `subNodes` was always the same instance?

So the subNodes number wasn't increased.

I think creating subNode should be in loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < catalog.nodes.size(); i++) 
    mainNodes = catalog.nodes.get(i);
    Log.i(TAG, "" + mainNodes.node.body);

    subNodes = new SubNodes(); // ADD THIS LINE 

    subNodes.setBody(mainNodes.node.body);

    subNodesList.add(subNodes);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```